# Do ADS12XX circuit need an amplifier?

Tags: amplifier, analog, adc, load-cell

I'm working on a project that use various analog sensors (load cells, microphone, pressure, etc.) All of them have an analog standard output (mv/V). I'm using a Raspberry Pi. I want to choose a module that can do continuous reading from these sensors.

Based on my search, I found that the HX711 module can do the job (amplification and digital conversion) and it has 24bits precision.

1. Will the ADS12XX (eg: ADS1263) integrated circuits from Texas Instruments amplify the signal or will I have to use an amplifier circuit?
2. Is there some IC like the HX711 that can do both things?

Comment: why not put AD7190 on the list

Answer (score 2):

Both the ADS1263 and HX711 have programmable gain amplifiers in front of their ADC units.

The PGA on the ADS1263 can be set to x1, x2, x4, x8, x16 or x32.

The PGA on the HX711 can be set to x32, x64 or x128.

Other TI chips that have PGAs include: ADS111x, ADS1018, ADS124x.

Comment: I can see that ADS1263 has 32bits resolution and HX711 has 24 bits, but as per your answer the HX711 amplifier is better. For better result should I favor resolution over amplification?

Comment: @Akram Why do you think HX711 has a better amplifier? Because it has higher gain doesn't mean better. More gain, means more noise and lees ENOB bits.

Comment: @MarkoBuršič I'm sorry as I'm very novice in electronics and that's why I came here seeking help of experts. So the real question here is why picking one versus the other? I'm trying to decide which one is better or maybe if you know another better circuit/module. It's for industrial instrumentation measurement and I really want to have something reliable and even better to have a plenty of libraries/resources. Any advice is welcome, thanks

Comment: @Akram The HX711 is a poor copy of the AD7190. You can order from AD the eval board, or buy a clone. This seems pretty well made: https://www.aliexpress.com/i/4000385663309.html

Comment: @MarkoBuršič thank you so much, your comment really helps.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if your project needs to use a load cell (and a Wheatstone bridge), then I think HX711 is the only choice, because it is specifically designed for that sort of application.

---

***References***

(1) [HX711 24-bit ADC Weight Sensor Response Time Q&A](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/566076/why-does-it-take-time-for-electronic-scale-to-measure)

---

Comment: I'm not sure why hx711 is the only choice? the reference you sent it only discuss that sensor, so no comparaison been made.

Comment: tlfong01 - Hi, Please delete comments that you leave on questions, when you add an answer which makes the comment obsolete. (I've just done that on 2 questions.) Thanks!

Comment: @SamGibson, OK, so I did that. Many thanks for your advice. Cheers.

Comment: @Akram, well, I studied both datasheets, and my opinion is that no comparison is required.